# Java Сортировка массива объектов по заполненности полей

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка, циклы, пузырьковая-сортировка

Дано:

1. Класс `Item` у него два поля:

   ```
   class Item {
       String name; 
       String description;
   }
   ```
2. Есть массив объектов `Item`. В конце массива несколько элементов целиком `null` и они должны остаться не тронутыми.

Нужно отсортировать таким образом чтобы все объекты у которых `description` равно `null` оказались в начале. Но элементы `null` (где объектов `Item` нет) должны остаться на месте.

Метод должен сохранять работоспособность при добавлении новых полей в класс `Item`.

> Item[] items = new Item[7];
>
> items[0].description = "abc";
>
> items[1].description = null;
>
> items[2].description = "abc"
>
> items[3].description = null;
>
> items[4] = null;
>
> items[5] = null;
>
> items[6] = null;

Искомый результат:

> items[0].description = null;
>
> items[1].description = null;
>
> items[2].description = "abc";
>
> items[3].description = "abc";
>
> items[4] = null;
>
> items[5] = null;
>
> items[6] = null;

Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: А почему у вас в метках стоит пузырьковая сортировка? Вам ее надо использовать?

Comment: Нет совершенно не обязательно. Просто мне показалось что она тут тоже понадобится вот и добавил. Возможно зря...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то вот этот код должен делать то, что вам нужно:

```
//компаратор для сравнения объектов по полю description
Comparator<Item> comparatorByDesc =
            (e1, e2) -> Comparator.<String>nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder()).compare(e1.description, e2.description);

//основной компаратор
Comparator<Item> generalComparator =
            (e1, e2) -> {
                if (e1 == null || e2 == null)
                    return Comparator.nullsLast(comparatorByDesc).compare(e1, e2);
                else
                    return comparatorByDesc.compare(e1, e2);
            };

itemList.sort(generalComparator);
```

Answer (score 1):

Используя `Comparator` и `Arrays.sort`

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Item[] items = new Item[7];
       items[0] = new Item("0", "abc");
       items[1] = new Item("1", null);
       items[2] = new Item("2", "abc");
       items[3] = new Item("3", null);
       items[4] = null;
       items[5] = null;
       items[6] = null;

       // Основная суть начинается здесь, остальное для тестового примера:
       Comparator<Item> c = new Comparator<Item>() {
          public int compare(Item i1, Item i2) {
             if(i1 == null && i2 == null)
                 return 0;
             if(i2 == null) 
                 return -1;
             if(i1 == null)
                 return 1;
             if(i1.description == null && i2.description == null) 
                return 0;
             if(i2.description == null) 
                return 1;
             if(i1.description == null) 
                return -1;
             return i1.description.compareTo(i2.description);
          }
       };

       Arrays.sort(items, c);
       // и вот до сюда.

       for (Item i : items)
          System.out.println(i) ;        
   }

   private static class Item {
       private String name;
       private String description; 

       public Item(String name, String description) {
           this.name = name; 
           this.description = description;
       }
       public String toString() {
          return "Item name: " + name + " description: " + description;
       }
   }
}
```